# Google Webmaster Tools can cache sitemap files?

Tags: google-search-console, sitemap, xml-sitemap

I'm struggling to submit my sitemaps to Google Webmaster Tools. Previously I received report that I have an error in all my sitemaps (the error was at `<image:image>` tag as I did not specified necessary [link](http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1) in the sitemap header). After the error was fixed I tried to resubmit the sitemaps but Google Webmaster Tools abused for me again and for the same line number (in my case: line 8, containing `<priority>0.7</priority>`). If I click on the sitemap file name - it is downloading OK (previously it was with 'red' header with list of detected errors).

So I really doubt that Google Webmaster Tools loading correct files. How can I make sure?

The beginning of my sitemaps is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
 xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">
  <url>
    <loc>Valid and tested link</loc>
    <lastmod>2014-02-03</lastmod>
    <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
    <priority>0.7</priority>
    <image:image>
      <image:loc>Valid and tested link</image:loc>
      <image:title>11-word description</image:title>
    </image:image>
  </url>
```

Comment: UPD: I just tried to provide "Test Sitemap". After "View test results" button I can see the amount of submitted pages and images and message "No errors found". I'm really confused :(

Comment: have you re-submitted the sitemap? If so this can take a couple of days to resolve. Also google webmaster tools can report error -+90 days after the issue occured

Comment: Oh, @Liam, really 90 days?! I have deleted and submitted the sitemaps again. So I will wait couple of days.

Comment: not specifically for the sitemaps themself but webmaster tools themselves when highlighting things link html errors, microdata ect can take upto, give or take a few days, 90 days

Comment: Yes, they cache it, it is frustrating.  Even their "test sitemap" tool caches it for awhile, which makes it impossible to test changes

Answer (score 2):

No, the sitemap is not cached. consider the file you upload as a config file that a program/system is going to use.

The process of recrawling your site may take some time, and adjusting the results according to the new sitemap may take some time, as mentioned, but the file itself is not cached.

Comment: Thanks! You answer is almost the same as mine. I just added the link to corresponding Google Help page.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Google keeps its right to keep error message for a while. The [Help Center page](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35738) says:

> Once you've reviewed your Sitemap and made any changes, save it and
>   then resubmit it. It can take **up to a day** for Google to process
>   the resubmitted Sitemap, so the warning status **may continue to
>   display** until then.

UPD (6 days after)! I'd like to report the changing to my situation. I didn't made any changes to site and after 6 days Webmaster Tools vanished all error reports and started to indexing my pages.